# Model value not set when passing into View in ASP.NET MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, model, routes

Stumped...

I have a few routes set up:

```
    Function AddUpdate(ByVal id As Long) As ActionResult
        Return View(New UPDATES With {.ID = id})
    End Function

    <HttpPost()> _
    Function AddUpdate(ByVal Update As UPDATES) As ActionResult
       //Do cool posted stuff here
    End Function
```

The type of the .ID is LONG.

When it runs the post function, the Update object's Update.ID is nothing.

My view doesn't alter the property, and I don't have any Helper methods attached to it in the view. Shouldn't it be sent back through to the post method?

Thanks - JB

Answer (score -1):

Is The id being sent back in the HTTP Post (using fiddler or firebug to see)?

Answer (score -1):

Are you actually passing the value back with POST, either through your route, or a form field? The ModelBinder can't bind values if it doesn't know where to look for them...